# Problem after update from Microsoft Identity Client 1 to 2,7

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-ad-msal

```
var scope = AzureAdB2COptions.ApiScopes.Split(' ');
    string signedInUserID = HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    TokenCache userTokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserID, this.HttpContext).GetMsalCacheInstance();
    ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(AzureAdB2COptions.ClientId, AzureAdB2COptions.Authority, AzureAdB2COptions.RedirectUri, new ClientCredential(AzureAdB2COptions.ClientSecret), userTokenCache, null);

    AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scope, cca.Users.FirstOrDefault(), AzureAdB2COptions.Authority, false);

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, AzureAdB2COptions.ApiUrl);

    // Add token to the Authorization header and make the request
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

with Microsoft Identity Client 1.0 the sampel code runs perfect.
After update to Microsoft Identity Client 2.7 I become two errors

> ClientApplicationBase.Users' is obsolete: 'Use GetAccountsAsync
>   instead (See
>   https://aka.ms/msal-net-2-released)'  WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet C:\Users\IDE00053\Downloads\active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp-master\WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet\Controllers\HomeController.cs

and

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.IUser' to
>   'Microsoft.Identity.Client.IAccount'  WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet C:\Users\IDE00053\Downloads\active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp-master\WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet\Controllers\HomeController.cs

at the code line

```
AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scope, cca.Users.FirstOrDefault(), AzureAdB2COptions.Authority, false);
```

Thanks for help
Stefan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were several changes made between MSALv1 and v2. Here is the [blog post](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/msal-net-2-released#changes-in-msalnet-between-1x-and-2x) which details the differences between the two. As noted in the error messages, the types that had fields or properties of type `IUser` now reference [`IAccount`](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/msal-net-2-released#impact-of-this-user---account-change-on-the-public-api). And `ClientApplicationBase.Users` becomes `GetAccountsAsync()`. 
Depending on your code, you'd need something like this:

```
IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
IAccount firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
try
{
    result = await app.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes, firstAccount);
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
{
    result = await app.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes, firstAccount);
}
accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
IAccount me = await app.GetAccountAsync(firstAccount.HomeAccountId.Identifier);
```

Here is a [B2C sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/) which has been updated to MSAL v2.

The team is also working on further changes to the public api (MSAL v3), which can be reviewed [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/810).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps a lot. 
But I still have on question regarding the architecture from asp.net core application. Is it better to use MSAL for authentication with Azure AD B2C or don’t use MSAL like on this site
http://codereform.com/blog/post/asp-net-core-2-0-authentication-with-azure-active-directory-b2c/

Regards
Stefan

Comment: @Stefan You can use the ASP.NET Core OpenID Connect Middleware, as used in this [b2c sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp), or you can use an OpenId Connect hybrid flow w/MSAL, as seen in this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp) (not on msalv2 yet). The 2nd sample shows how to use [MSAL](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp#initial-token-acquisition) to redeem the auth code for an access token, which is saved in a cache to be used later on.